# Select2 - incorrect selected value with mysql data

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I am using [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) for my dropdown option. I am populating it in a table form with MySQL data and the form is inside a bootstrap Modal, together with the button to edit or delete.

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Area</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        <span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <?php
        echo "<li><a class=\"open-EditRow\" data-areano=\"".$areano."\" data-area=\"".$area."\" data-centerno=\"".$centerno."\" title=\"Edit this row\" \"><i class=\"fa fa-pencil\"></i> Edit</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a class=\"open-DeleteRow\" data-areano=\"".$areano."\" data-area=\"".$area."\" data-centerno=\"".$centerno."\" title=\"Delete this row\" \"><i class=\"fa fa-trash\"></i> Delete</a></li>";
        ?>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Then the Edit button will open a Modal to edit details.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Center</label>
  <div class="col-sm-5">
  <?php                         
    $e = mysql_query("select * from center") or die(mysql_error());
  ?>
    <select class="populate placeholder" name="center" id="center">
        <option value="">-- Select a center --</option>
        <?php
        while($f=mysql_fetch_array($e))
        {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $f['center_no']; ?>" <?php if ($f['center_no']==$centerno) { ?>selected<?php } ?>><?php echo $f['center']; ?></option>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is how I pass the data to the Modal:

```
$('.open-EditRow').click(function(){
   var areano = $(this).attr('data-areano');
   var area = $(this).attr('data-area');
   var centerno = $(this).attr('data-centerno');
   $('#myModal #areano').val(areano);
   $('#myModal #area').val(area);
   $('#myModal #center').val(centerno);
   $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

And the Select2 code:

```
function DemoSelect2(){
    $('#center').select2();
}
```

But Select2 is displaying incorrect selected value. It is displaying the first item generated by the query, instead of the selected value.

[image]

But upon clicking the Select2 dropdown, the selected item is highlighted correctly.

[image]

What seems to be the problem here? Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you expand your question to also include a snippet of the HTML that is being generated? The issue might be in the HTML, but it also could be that you are not triggering the `change` event after calling `val()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround I did for this, and it somehow worked is to first remove the if statement which was used to compare the data. So my option just looked like this:

```
<option value="<?php echo $f['center_no']; ?>"><?php echo $f['center']; ?></option>
```

And then I declared the selected value on the `function DemoSelect2()`

```
function DemoSelect2(){
    var centerno = $(this).attr('data-centerno');
    $('#center').select2("val", centerno);
}
```

Now, my Select2 dropdown looked like this:

[image]

Upon clicking the dropdown, it highlighted the correct selected value:

[image]

I don't know if this is the correct fix for this but, this worked for me.